# Hypercyclicity examples

Tags: chaos-theory

Does anyone have simple practical examples of hypercyclicity they use in explaining the concept (graphically or numerically)?  This appears often in texts about chaos in infinite dimensional linear spaces in trying to satisfy the DeVaney definition of chaos.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://interstices.info/le-chaos-lineaire-un-paradoxe/) you have a fantastic outreach work on linear chaos due to Grosse-Erdmann and Menet. It is in french (I have a spanish translation in my own blog if you prefered it).

Appart the classical examples of multiples of the BAckward shift or composition operators, I think this work is the best thing you can get.